# How to correctly define an element in XSD for a custom log4net appender child element

Tags: xml, xsd, log4net

I am new to log4net and need to include a custom Appender. I have the following defined in **log4net.config** for my custom appender:

```
<appender name="SyslogAppender" type="log4net.Appenders.RemoteAppender,log4net.Appenders">
  <AppName>MySampleApp</AppName>
</appender>
```

In **log4net.xsd**, I have

```
 <xs:complexType name="appender">
    ...
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AppName" type="AppName" />
    ...
 </xs:complexType>
```

I am trying to define **AppName** so that I can properly use it. I have tried using:

```
 <xs:complexType name="AppName">
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:complexType>
```

I am getting the error, **The element cannot contain text. Content model is empty.** When I use **xs:element** it tells me that the element is not supported in this context.

I also tried using

```
 <xs:element name="AppName" type="xs:string" />
```

How can I define this properly to use **AppName** like I want to in **log4net.config**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I moved this all to Web.config and didn't have to use the XSD anymore. This solved my issue. Probably not the best solution, but worked.